# Client side blazor app, sending notification to a app on a computer when a button is pressed

Tags: notifications, client, blazor

I have a blazor client side app displaying data from a database, and the user can select an item enter some text and press a button to indicate the message has been acknowledged. 
My c# .net app on a computer is writing data to the same database via rest api's, time stamped records. How can I get a notification to the source app indicating that the message has been viewed with the text entered ?

The only way I can see this is being done is via polling the database for an updated record, or am I looking for some sort of subscription that can notify the app on the computer ?

Comment: There are lots of ways this could be done. Polling would work like you suggested, but I probably wouldn't do it. You could also, after you save the data to the table, hit an API to let the source app know to check for changes. You could also use something like Azure Logic Apps

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is polling but it's inefficient, ugly, nasty on your network and will eat memory in the browser, which you don't want.

You haven't mentioned which database.  Postgres can do notifications natively, Oracle can probably do it for all the money in the known world and some of the NoSQL DB's have it built-in, including Google's Firebase and an open source .NET db called Sapphire.  Sql Server can do it via SqlDependency (part of the System.Data namespace) but your DB user will need permission to create Service Broker queues, which, of course, must be enabled.

Once your WebAPI has the notification, however you achieve this, you can push it to a Blazor Webassembly in a variety of ways.  The Server Push API is neat, one-way (perfect for you) but not universally supported and will require Javascript Interop.  A service worker could run the Notifications API but that again requires Interop and users tend to block website notifications on instinct. I certainly do.

Finally, there's WebSockets, which are now supported natively in Blazor or there's SignalR which also has native support.  Both of these are duplex and therefore overkill for your needs but they're probably the easiest to implement and debug, if not to secure or scale.

Or you could use gRPC but that's even more like overkill.

Comment: For anyone reading there is also [Stl.Fusion](https://github.com/servicetitan/Stl.Fusion) which I am still trying to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 0):

Use *ASP.NET Core SignalR*

- [Official SignalR Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
- [ASP.NET Core Blazor SignalR guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly)